# Why haven't I earned Yearling badge?

Tags: support, badges, yearling-badge

Today I should have earned the Yearling badge on [Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/), but I haven't. All conditions for the badge should be fulfilled. I have earned this badge on some other SE sites before and it seems the corresponding script for this badge is running somewhere between 12.00 and 13.00, at least this is the time I used to earn this badge before.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you hover over the ['1 year' in your profile](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/41763/convert) you see the complete timestamp: 2022-01-23 22:31:49Z.

[image: convert, member for 1 year, hover text: 2022-01-23 22:31:49Z]

When I'm writing this, it's January 23rd 20:29 UTC, so you are not yet one year old, that takes two hours more. Then wait 24 hours, and I'm sure you'll have your Yearling badges. Plural, because you'll earn one on Politics Meta as well.